# MySQL subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, mysql

I am executing this query:

```
SELECT
    voterfile_county.Name,
    voterfile_precienct.PREC_ID,
    voterfile_precienct.Name,
    COUNT((SELECT voterfile_voter.ID
FROM voterfile_voter
JOIN voterfile_household
WHERE voterfile_voter.House_ID = voterfile_household.ID
AND voterfile_household.Precnum = voterfile_precienct.PREC_ID)) AS Voters
FROM voterfile_precienct JOIN voterfile_county
WHERE voterfile_precienct.County_ID = voterfile_County.ID;
```

I am trying to make it return something like this:

```
County_Name   Prec_ID   Prec_Name   Voters(Count of # of voters in that precienct)
```

However, I am getting the error:

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

I have tried placing the `COUNT` statement in the subquery but I get an invalid syntax error.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica stop being smart-ass. This data is public. You can get it yourself for learning purposes.

Comment: @Eimantas His question history and comments on the answer seem to suggest otherwise.  Either way, I'm done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try it without the subquery, with a simple group by:

```
SELECT voterfile_county.Name, 
  voterfile_precienct.PREC_ID, 
  voterfile_precienct.Name, 
  count(voterfile_voter.ID)
FROM voterfile_county
JOIN voterfile_precienct 
  ON voterfile_precienct.County_ID = voterfile_County.ID
JOIN voterfile_household 
  ON voterfile_household.Precnum = voterfile_precienct.PREC_ID
JOIN voterfile_voter 
  ON voterfile_voter.House_ID = voterfile_household.ID 
GROUP BY voterfile_county.Name, 
  voterfile_precienct.PREC_ID, 
  voterfile_precienct.Name
```

When you use GROUP BY, any column that you are not grouping on must have an aggregate clause (f.e. SUM or COUNT.)  So in this case you have to group on county name, precienct.id and precient.name.

Comment: that worked, it took 92.5746 seconds to execute and return the result set though. any thoughts on how to speed that up?

Comment: Do you have foreign keys for the relations? That might help.

Comment: add indexes for all the columns used in the joins to speed it up.  If the result set is large, anything you do to make it smaller will also speed it up.

Answer (score 63):

If you get error:error no 1242 Subquery returns more than one row, try to put ANY before your subquery. Eg:

This query return error:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);
```

This is good query:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = ANY (SELECT column1 FROM t2);
```

Comment: Why does column1 = ANY(subquery) work and not column1 IN (subquery)? Does it not recreate the same relational logic?

Comment: This solved my problem with updating rows based on a select statement from the same table.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT
voterfile_county.Name, voterfile_precienct.PREC_ID, 
voterfile_precienct.Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(voterfile_voter.ID) 
    FROM voterfile_voter JOIN voterfile_household
    WHERE voterfile_voter.House_ID = voterfile_household.ID
      AND voterfile_household.Precnum = voterfile_precienct.PREC_ID) as Voters
FROM voterfile_precienct JOIN voterfile_county 
ON voterfile_precienct.County_ID = voterfile_County.ID
```

Comment: it just says query is being executed, which is farther than i have gotten. but no dice.

Comment: are you getting a syntax error? or is it just executing indefinitely, if so, is it much data inside the tables for query?

Answer (score 3):

See the below example and modify your query accordingly.

```
select COUNT(ResultTPLAlias.id) from 
(select id from Table_name where .... ) ResultTPLAlias;
```