# subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

```
select 
    disease_name 
from 
    disease 
where 
    disease_id=
    (select disease_id from disease_symptom where
        disease.disease_id=disease_symptom.disease_id AND 
        symptom_id=
               (select symptom_id from symptom where symptom.symptom_id=disease_symptom.symptom_id
                AND symptom_name='fever' OR symptom_name='head ache'))
```

Gives an error that subquery returns more than one row.  what is the cause?

Comment: I guess I'll be the one to state the obvious: the subquery returns more than one row.  `disease_id` cannot equal multiple values.  This query would be better written with `JOIN`s instead of subqueries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3423792/2806972 c this may be get solution for this Q:

Answer (score 18):

Your two outer queries are structured to expect a single result from the their subqueries. But the way you have things structured, your subqueries might return more than one result. If you actually *want* more than one result, restructure it like this:

```
... where disease_id IN (subquery returning multiple rows...)
```

Also, subqueries is kill performance, and it's exponentially wosrse for nested subqueries. You might want to look into using `INNER JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Breaking your query down, you have

Main query:

```
select disease_name from disease where disease_id=
```

Subquery 1:

```
select disease_id from disease_symptom where
        disease.disease_id=disease_symptom.disease_id AND 
        symptom_id=
```

Sub query 2:

```
select symptom_id from symptom where symptom.symptom_id=disease_symptom.symptom_id
            AND symptom_name='fever' OR symptom_name='head ache'
```

Since you are using equal signs, the subqueries cannot return multiple items. It looks like sub query 2 has a greater chance to return 2 items due to the `OR` being used. You may wish to try `IN` clause such as `WHERE symptom_id IN (sub-query2)` with `WHERE disease_id IN (sub-query1)`