# mysql count results with an identical field

Tags: php, mysql, count

So I'm fairly new to web development and I haven't really used php and mysql much before.

I was wanting to query my database to find out how many results had the same value for a certain field. I was thinking along the following lines:

```
SELECT value_a, COUNT(*)
FROM table_a
WHERE value_a = (SELECT DISTINCT value_a FROM table_a)
```

but obviously I can't have multiple values from my inner query. How could I do something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subquery returns more than 1 row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841945/subquery-returns-more-than-1-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do -

IF you want to check a single value -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) value_a_count
FROM table_a
WHERE value_a = 'value_to_check'
GROUP BY value_a
```

Or for every values -

```
SELECT value_a, COUNT(*) value_a_count
FROM table_a
GROUP BY value_a
```

Comment: will do in 5 minutes when it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

put your result(check_value) in this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count_value
FROM table_a
WHERE value_a IN (check_value)
GROUP BY value_a
```