# Why do I get sub query returning more than one row?

Tags: sql, subquery, advantage-database-server

I am using Advantage Database Server.

I have one table `Areas` and I want to find out all the child nodes of parent area.

The table and column names are:

```
Areas
(
    AreaID INTEGER
  , Name   NVARCHAR(50)
  , Code   NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

The stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAreaLocations
(
    AreaID     INTEGER
  , AreaOutID  INTEGER       OUTPUT
  , AreaName   NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
  , AreaCode   NVARCHAR(50)  OUTPUT
  , WithParent NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
  , DepthSpace NVARCHAR(50)  OUTPUT
  , Depth      INTEGER       OUTPUT
  , ParentID   INTEGER       OUTPUT
)
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    AID          INTEGER
  , depthid      INTEGER
  , tempdepth    INTEGER
  , depthspaceid NVARCHAR(50)
;

AID          = (SELECT AreaID FROM __input);
depthid      = 1;
depthspaceid = '';

INSERT INTO 
  __output
SELECT TOP 50
    A.AreaID
  , A.Name
  , A.Code
  , (SELECT Name + '->' + A.Name FROM Areas WHERE AreaID = A.ParentID)
  , depthspaceid
  , depthid
  , AID
FROM 
  Areas A 
WHERE 
  A.ParentID = AID 
ORDER BY 
  A.AreaID ASC
;

IF (SELECT COUNT(AreaOutID) FROM __output) > 0 THEN

SELECT TOP 1 
    AID     = AreaOutID
  , depthid = Depth
FROM
  __output 
WHERE
  ParentID = AID
ORDER BY
  AreaOutID ASC
;

WHILE depthid > 0 DO
WHILE AID > 0 DO

INSERT INTO 
  __output
SELECT 
    AreaID
  , Name
  , Code
  , Name
  , (SELECT CASE WHEN WithParent IS NULL THEN '' ELSE WithParent + '->' + Name END FROM __output WHERE AreaOutID=AID)
  , depthspaceid
  , depthid + 1
  , AID 
FROM 
  Areas
WHERE
  ParentID = AID
;

AID = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 AreaOutID FROM __output WHERE Depth=depthid and AreaOutID > AID ORDER BY AreaOutID ASC),0);

END WHILE;

tempdepth = depthid;
AID       = 0;
depthid   = 0;

SELECT TOP 1 
    depthid = Depth
  , AID     = AreaOutID
FROM 
  __output
WHERE 
  depthid > tempdepth
ORDER BY
    depthid ASC
  , AreaOutID ASC
;
WND WHILE;
END IF;
END;
```

I'm getting an error about a subquery returning more than one row.

What's causing it and how to fix it?

Comment: There are lots of similar questions, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778239/mysql-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row

Comment: The basic answer is because there are more than one. Usual approach is to use an aggregate e.g. min or max, or a limit. How though depends on the source data and what you are trying to retrieve from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `subquery` as an `expression` you have to make sure that it doesn't return more than one row.

This can be done in the `subquery` by:

- `SELECT TOP 1`
- `SELECT DISTINCT` (Won't work for all cases)
- `GROUP BY` (Won't work for all cases)
- `SELECT COUNT(*)`
- Careful constructed `WHERE` conditions and Constraints on the database

You can also turn the `subquery` into a `JOIN` when it is used as part of another query, but this will lead to more rows in the main query if not done correctly.

In other databases there are also `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` or `ANY` clauses to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data and seeing that all other subqueries have TOP 1 included, I think that the following subquery must be returning >1 row:

```
(SELECT CASE WHEN WithParent IS NULL THEN '' ELSE WithParent + '->' + Name END FROM __output WHERE AreaOutID=AID)
```